# Python - Caesar Cipher Error

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a Caesar cipher in python however I have encountered an error.
My code is:

```
print("Enter desired function.")
print("1 - Encode")
print("2 - Decode")
function = input("")
if function == "1":
    print("How much do you want to offset it by?")
    offset = int(input(""))
elif function == "2":
    print("How much is it offset by?")
    offset = int(input("")) * -1
print("Enter the message.")
message = input("")
upperMessage = message.upper
length = len(message)
for i in range(length):
    letter = upperMessage[i-1]
    number = ord(letter)
    offsetNumber = number + offset
    if offsetNumber > 90:
        highOffset = offsetNumber - 90
        offsetNumber = 65 + highOffset
    if offsetNumber < 65:
        lowOfsset = 65 - offsetNumber
        offsetNumber = lowOffset + 90
    newLetter[i-1] = chr(offsetNumber)
 print(newLetter)
```

It runs fine to begin with but when I enter the message I receive the error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I have tried replacing the line

```
letter = upperMessage[i-1]
```

with

```
letter = upperMessage(i-1)
```

but this returns the error

```
TypeError: upper() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Can you please help me?
Many thanks,
RFox

Comment: You mean `upperMessage = message.upper()` - note parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parentheses to actually call the method

```
upperMessage = message.upper()
```

Otherwise you are assigning the function itself to `upperMessage`, similar(-ish) to a function pointer if you are familiar with C++.